# How to take a value from stdin when unsure if it's an int or a char?

Tags: c

How would one go about taking a value of `stdin` when it could be either a character (p or q in this case) or an integer value above zero but below a max?

I have tried using the `%c` conversion character but find that this means it loses anything after the first digit (obviously as it would just take a single char)

Should I be using `%i` instead or do I need to do it a different way? I found `%i` returns 0 for anything not an integer but this would then only allow me to check if it were not an int rather than a specific char?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the return value of scanf:

```
if (scanf("%d", &intInput) == 0) {
    /* Nothing read. Not an integer! */
    scanf("%c", &charInput);
    /* Process char input */
} else {
    /* Process integer input */
```

Answer (score 0):

Check it: `isaplha` for a charachter, and `isdigit` for a number.

Comment: I thought that those were only c++ functions?

Comment: @user262751 they are standard C.